# How to scrape UrbanDictionary Definitions using JSoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I have tried using JSoup API but it seems JSoup don't separate the meaning portion when scraping

```
public class JSoupScraper {
    public static void main(String[] args){
            Document doc=null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=word").get();
            Elements meanings=doc.select("div");
            for(Element meaning:meanings){
                System.out.println(meaning.attr("class","meaning"));
            }        
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JSoupScraper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Undo, thanks for the change, forgot that I was using it for my Inappropriate Expressions Recognizer that is why my example is kind of inappropriate.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'scraping the meaning portion'. Are you trying to get all the `div`s that have a `class='meaning'`?

Comment: What you're currently doing in your code, is setting the `class` attribute of all `div`s in the document to `'meaning'`.

Comment: yes. I want to retrieve the data in text

Answer (score 0):

`doc.select("div[class=meaning]")` will return all `div` elements with a `class="meaning"` attribute set.

see the *Jsoup* [selector-syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the help in the JSoup problem